# Анимация при движении курсора

Tags: javascript, анимация

Нуждаюсь в помощи с анимацией при движении курсора. Нужна такая же анимация с этого сайта https://unitk.ai/ с фоном при движении курсора с помощью JS, как я понимаю

Comment: https://www.curtainsjs.com/

Comment: Pavel Nazarian дал сайт с этой библиотекой (curtainsjs.com), разобралась - помогло!